# How to make an appropriate array for coordinates?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that returns 28 (latitude and longitude). I'll format to send to database, so here my questions:

1. As you can see, the latitude and longitude comes always together, how can i separate?
   2.the bold lines always return the same coordinate, how can I remove to send the minimal to database?

Code below:

```
var capturaCoordenada = [];

if (data.waypoints.length === 12) {
        for (var i = 0; i < capturaCoordenada.length; i++) {
        exibeCoordenada = exibeCoordenada + "\n" + capturaCoordenada[i] + capturaCoordenada[i++]; }
        exibeCoordenada = exibeCoordenada + "\n";

    window.alert(exibeCoordenada);
```

OBS: I receive the coordinates like this:
Data:

***-49.3766505877158,-20.80796326493855-49.3766505877158***,-20.80796326493855
-49.37949730565916,-20.80670816431558-49.37949730565916,-20.80670816431558
-49.38166453054308,-20.805324135912116-49.38166453054308,-20.805324135912116
-49.38413216283695,-20.806146531132384-49.38413216283695,-20.806146531132384
-49.38209368398577,-20.80891456013579-49.38209368398577,-20.80891456013579
-49.37981917074134,-20.81096046195445-49.37981917074134,-20.81096046195445
-49.37743736913569,-20.811140981370414-49.37743736913569,-20.811140981370414

Comment: Do you receive the data as a single string, without enters (`\n`)?

Comment: Yes, they come from a user visual interaction in the screen.

Comment: are the pairs `49.3766505877158,-20.80796326493855` or `-20.80796326493855-49.3766505877158`

Answer (score 0):

in this part of the code

```
exibeCoordenada = exibeCoordenada + "\n" + capturaCoordenada[i] + capturaCoordenada[i++];
```

You are adding the same thing twice, try removing one of them, like this:

```
exibeCoordenada = exibeCoordenada + "\n" + capturaCoordenada[i];
```

Then you should have a result looking like the following

```
-49.3766505877158,-20.80796326493855
-49.37949730565916,-20.80670816431558
-49.38166453054308,-20.805324135912116
```

You should be able to convert the string into a list like so:

```
exibeCoordenada.split("\n").map(x => x.split(","))
```

Which gives you this:

```
[["-49.3766505877158", "-20.80796326493855"], ["-49.37949730565916", "-20.80670816431558"], ["-49.38166453054308", "-20.805324135912116"]]
```